# PHP- Can apache make more than one response per request to 'stream' data?

Tags: php, linux, apache

Aim: to send a stream of data to the server, and that data to be streamed back in realtime as the transfer is happening using PHP (with only **one** webserver request)

Objectives complete So far: I have worked out that the PUT method is the only one which php/apache is able to read bit by bit as it is being received (using file_get_contents & Php:input wrapper). I have worked out that the only way to make a PUT request in a browser (without addons), is to do it via ajax, fine.

The next objective is to deliver the data back to the browser (in real time). If there is a possibility to deliver more responses than requests, this could be possible right? Without binding to ports for sockets or installing any third party software/apache modules, is there a way to do this? (On the screen would be a stream of data and your browser slide bar would get progressively smaller, just to visualise).

Comment: Why not use WebSocket?

Comment: because I can't use any of the ports.

Comment: WebSocket can be deployed on the same port with http server, using nginx as reverse proxy.

Comment: that falls under the "third party" category, which I also cannot do. sorry i know u are only trying to help, but this is why "why" questions are so tiring and why I specify the conditions in the original post.